# Python loop error - Its runs fine for 6 character strings but falls apart for more than that

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, python-requests, syntax-error

Task
Given a string, of given length that is indexed from  to , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as  space-separated strings on a single line.
As you can see it works fine for grace but does not handle thomasshelby the same way. Can you tell me, what is the problem with this code?

```
length = int(input()) 
k=1
while k <= length:
    name = input()
    name1 = name2 = ""
    for i in name:
        if name.index(i)%2 == 0:
            name1 = name1 + i

    for j in name:
        if name.index(j)%2 != 0:
            name2 = name2 + j

    print(name1,name2)
    k += 1
```

and here is the result

```
2

thomasshelby
toaeb hmsshly

grace
gae rc
```

Comment: string's "index" method always returns the position of the **first** occurrence of the searched string. Don't use it and see what "enumerate" can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use string slicing for odd even characters

check below example:

```
name = input()
name1 = name[::2]
name2 = name[1::2])
```

Comment: Thanks bro . It really helped . but can you spot anything in that chunk of code? it would really help in future.

Comment: @sam in your code you are using string.index which give index of first occurance of character. If you have duplicate charactors in word it wont work.

Comment: you can use enumerate function which give you all the indexes and the characters

Answer (score 0):

The `str.index` method returns the minimum index value.

This is the description of the method:

```
    def index(self, sub, start=None, end=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """
        S.index(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
        
        Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
        such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
        arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
        
        Raises ValueError when the substring is not found.
        """
```

So in your program, when the input string has the same element present, It's not going to be ideal.

Comment: thanks la lot bro . hopefully, it will be helpful in near future

Answer (score 0):

you can use an index loop variable instead of index built-in method :

```
length = int(input()) 
k=1
while k <= length:
    name = input()
    name1 = name2 = ""
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            name1 = name1 + name[i]

    for j in range(len(name)):
        if j%2 != 0:
            name2 = name2 + name[j]

    print(name1,name2)
    k += 1
```